# ODBC Driver 13 and ODBC Driver 11

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, sql-server-2016

Can I install both ODBC Driver 13 and ODBC Driver 11 on the same server? 
I need to access Microsoft SQL 2008 database and Microsoft SQL 2016 database. First one requires ODBC Driver 11. Second one requires ODBC Driver 13.
Would they be independently use by the system?
Update:
I have installed both drivers 11 and 13. I still can't work with my 2008 database.
Not sure if I need to restart? Did not restart as installation did not ask for it.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet. Was waiting for someone to answer as I worried I might break something. Or not? Any thoughts?

Comment: does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can simultaneously install [ODBC 11 and 13|13.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files) since the filenames are different and even Microsoft suggests you can change the connection string.  (I do not have yet a server with SQL 2016 on testing environment.  Therefore, I can not test it).

How to differentiate which application will use which?

To quote from the Microsoft's pages:

> When an application uses the driver, the application should indicate
>   that it depends on the driver through the install option APPGUID.
>   Doing so enables the driver installer to report dependent applications
>   before uninstalling. To specify a dependency on the driver, set the
>   APPGUID command-line parameter to your product code when silently
>   installing the driver. (A product code must be created when using
>   Microsoft Installer to bundle your application setup program.) For
>   example:

```
msiexec /i msodbcsql.msi APPGUID={ <Your dependent application's APPGUID> }
```